# How to fix mcsb_container scrolling issues?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am implementing a chat section in my project ,but there is some issues in UI.

Which I am unable to fix it .Here after scrolling some extra spaces is coming as well as i want to slow down the scrolling speed.

I have attached some screen shorts .

Can anyone please suggest me , where is the problem ??

[image]

[image]

In the second there is coming some spaces after the chat ,i marked there some top is adding automatically .

I did not get much idea about it .

I added some codes

```html
 <script>
    (function($){
        $(window).on("load",function(){
            $(".session-chat-body, .session-view-student").mCustomScrollbar();
        });
    })(jQuery);
  </script>
```

```html
$("#mCSB_2").animate({ scrollTop: $('#mCSB_2_container').prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000);
```

I am guessing this 1000 is creating problem.

Thank you

Comment: you should write here code.

Comment: @Parth Trivedi I have edited it.

Comment: 1000 is animation timing. If you want to slow down animation then increase animation delay. like 5000.

Comment: ok.,that one i have fixed ..i have issues with height

Comment: you should try `$('#mCSB_2_container').prop("scrollHeight")-500`